# Using Burstly and Adfonic together

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am getting the error while i am integrating Adfonic and Burstly Ad integration Frameworks are  at a same time.

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_LoadingView.actIndicator in:
    /Users/kunalthakkar/kunal/displayAds/AdfonicSDK/libAdfonic.a(ORMMAAVPlayer.o)
    /Users/kunalthakkar/kunal/displayAds/BurstlySDK/libBurstly.a(BurstlyORMMAAVPlayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_LoadingView in:
    /Users/kunalthakkar/kunal/displayAds/AdfonicSDK/libAdfonic.a(ORMMAAVPlayer.o)
    /Users/kunalthakkar/kunal/displayAds/BurstlySDK/libBurstly.a(BurstlyORMMAAVPlayer.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_LoadingView in:
    /Users/kunalthakkar/kunal/displayAds/AdfonicSDK/libAdfonic.a(ORMMAAVPlayer.o)
    /Users/kunalthakkar/kunal/displayAds/BurstlySDK/libBurstly.a(BurstlyORMMAAVPlayer.o)
ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: may be you are linked some class twise check please

Comment: already checked but not working